# On Kivy's Clock, I want Change the Label color

Tags: python, kivy

I want to change text color by passing the time.
I use Python and kivy.
This is my code.In this code, only a label come on.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random

class MyLabel(Label):
    def callback(self, *arg):
        self.evt = Clock.schedule_interval(self.callback, 1)

    def on_value(self, *arg):
        self.parent.lbl.color = random.choice(['red','blue','black'])


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout=BoxLayout()
        layout.lbl = Label(text='NESIA')
        layout.add_widget(layout.lbl)
        return layout

MyApp().run()
```

`

Comment: Shouldn't you have `layout.lbl = MyLabel(text='NESIA')` instead of `layout.lbl = Label(text='NESIA')` in your `MyApp` `build` method? It looks like you created a custom label class but then used the default one in the actual app.

Comment: Thank you. I change that. However, I cannot change the color. "on_value" is one of the mistake?

Comment: When you call on_value?

Comment: Actually, I cannnot understand the way to call on_value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call the `on_value()` method you define. What you can do is use `Clock.schedule_interval()` when you build the app, passing in the method that changes the label's colour and the interval in which you want it to be called like so:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import random

class MyLabel(Label):
    def change_color(self, *args):
        r, g, b = random.choice([[1, 0, 0],[0,0,1],[ 1, 1, 1]])
        self.color = [r, g, b, 1]

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout()
        label = MyLabel(text='NESIA')
        Clock.schedule_interval(label.change_color, 1)
        layout.add_widget(label)
        return layout

MyApp().run()
```

This is assuming what you want is to have a label with the text `NESIA` whose colour is randomly set to red, blue, or black every second. Note that it's possible that `random.choice()` returns the same colour twice in a row, meaning it will look like it's not changing for however many seconds that happens for.